# How to disable source map or debug mode in production Vue.js - Webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am working on a **Vue.js** project and all files are generated by **webpack** on dev and production mode.

but here is my problem :

***I can see my vue components in devtools when I inspect on a element.***

How could I disable that ?

By the way source map is disabled and I have no .map files in dist folder.
[image: Here is my devtools and as you can see vue components are showed]

thank you :)

Comment: Can you post your webpack configuration?

Comment: @CodyG. here is my webpack.prod.conf gist url and as you can see i disabled extractTextplugin because order of css was wrong in prod

Comment: @CodyG. https://gist.github.com/HamidOsouli/c4303b966d8665b9fe8633544bece068

Comment: Don't you need a vue-loader ? How are your vue components being compiled?

Comment: @CodyG. I have a vue loader, my project is with vue-webpack-template. What should I do ?

Comment: There are lots of "vue-webpack-template" I can't guess which one, you should look at the vue-loader area and make sure the source maps are turned off and/or getting the correct environment (prod vs dev) variable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just checkout the [Vue cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#productionsourcemap):

> **productionSourceMap Type:** boolean
>
> Default: true
>
> Setting this to false can speed up production builds if you don't need
>   source maps for production.

So in your webpack config you write:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false
};
```

If your `vue.config.js` which is responsible for your webpack configuration doesn't exist, you may create it.

Comment: thank you it worked, now all of styles are inlined in production, just a question : is it ok to disable extractTextPlugin and move styles to inlined in production mode ?

Answer (score 1):

If webpack has been configured from scratch, it can be removed by deleting or commenting in any case in the webpack production file
the devtool option

**tools/webpack.prod.js**

```
    module.exports = merge(common, {
      // devtool: "source-map",
      mode: "production",
      ...
    });
```