# I can see source files of my compiled Vue project

Tags: node.js, vue.js

When I am building my project and uploading it on hosting, i can see source .vue files. How can I prevent users from seeing .vue files?
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6oMY.png)

I am using vue.js 3 with vue router. In router I am using lazy-load with help of webpack.
I am building this project with command `vue-cli-service build`.

I havent found how to solve this problem in internet, so I tried to edit config files and webpack configs, but it gived any result

Comment: You should be building for production with webpack, which will minify and combine all the files into an unreadable, optimized chunk. https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

Comment: you need to disable source maps on prod

Comment: and how can i disable it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028103